# Factory pattern for compile time

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

I am trying to figure out the right design for this problem

I have three classes Thread, Consumer, and Event

```
public class Thread {
    private Consumer _consumer = new Consumer();
}

public class Consumer {
    private someMethod() {
        Event event = new Event();
        // do something with event 
    }
}
```

In my "main" T is created and its dependencies are encapsulated

```
Thread t = new Thread();
```

Now the design has changed and we need multiple `Consumer`s and each one of them should construct a different `Event`. The code is same for all so I don't need to change `Consumer`.

I tried to do it with generics, as it looks like this is a simple and clean way. However, it looks like it is not possible to use **new** on generic type.
(Misguided by C++ templates)

```
public class Thread<T extends Event> {
    private Consumer _c = new Consumer<T>();
}

public class Consumer<T extends Event> {
    private someMethod() {
        Event event = new T();
    }
}
```

My other option is to pass some kind of compile time factory

```
public interface IEventFactory {
    public Event create();
}

public class EventFactory implements IEventFactory{
    public Event create() {
        return new Event1();
    }
}

public class Thread {
    private Consumer _consumer;

    public Thread (IEventFactory _factory) {
        _consumer = new Consumer(_factory);
    }
}

public class Consumer {
    private IEventFactory _factory;

    public C(IEventFactory factory) {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    private someMethod() {
        Event event = _factory.create();
    }
}
```

This solution feels less elegant passing the factory all the way down.
Is there a better and more elegant way approaching this?

Comment: @Michael thank you for your comment and edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factory is adding nothing but boilerplate here. You can accomplish the same thing with a method reference: pass the `Event`'s constructor into `Consumer`'s constructor. Use the [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) functional interface to do this.

```
public class Consumer<T extends Event> {
    private final Supplier<T> eventConstructor;

    public Consumer(final Supplier<T> eventConstructor) {
        this.eventConstructor = eventConstructor;
    }

    private void someMethod() {
        final T event = eventConstructor.get();
    }
}
```

You can propagate up the constructor from the `Thread`:

```
class Thread<T extends Event> {
    private Consumer<T> consumer;

    public Thread(final Supplier<T> eventConstructor) {
        this.consumer = new Consumer<>(eventConstructor);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Thread<Event1> thr = new Thread<>(Event1::new);
```

This will also work if certain events have constructor parameters, for example:

```
Thread<Event2> thr2 = new Thread<>(() -> new Event2("some default"));
```

Comment: This is great, thank you... However now I face another challenge. I need to pass arguments to Event when created. I.E. Event event = new Event(payload, offset);

Comment: @Nir You should post another question