# Factory pattern for compile time (with arguments)

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

Following my previous question, [Factory pattern for compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50813355/factory-pattern-for-compile-time), apparently, I oversimplified my code example and missed parts of the problem of passing arguments to the **Event** instance

I am trying to figure out the right design for this problem

I have three classes **Thread**, **Consumer**, and **Event**

```
public class Thread {
    private Consumer _consumer = new Consumer();
}

public class Consumer {
    private someMethod() {
        Event event = new Event(arg1, arg2);
        // do something with event 
    }
}
```

In my "main" T is created and its dependencies are encapsulated

```
Thread t = new Thread();
```

Now the design has changed and we need multiple `Consumer`s and each one of them should construct a different `Event`. The code is same for all so I don't need to change `Consumer`.

I tried to do it with generics, as it looks like this is a simple and clean way. However, it looks like it is not possible to use **new** on generic type.
(Misguided by C++ templates)

```
public class Thread<T extends Event> {
    private Consumer _c = new Consumer<T>();
}

public class Consumer<T extends Event> {
    private someMethod() {
        Event event = new T(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

My other option is to pass some kind of compile time factory

```
public interface IEventFactory {
    public Event create(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2);
}

public class EventFactory implements IEventFactory{
    public Event create(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2) {
        return new Event1(arg1, arg2);
    }
}

public class Thread {
    private Consumer _consumer;

    public Thread (IEventFactory _factory) {
        _consumer = new Consumer(_factory);
    }
}

public class Consumer {
    private IEventFactory _factory;

    public C(IEventFactory factory) {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    private someMethod() {
        Event event = _factory.create(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

Is there a better and more elegant way approaching this?

Comment: Are the arguments for each event always the same?

Comment: Use `BiFunction<Arg1, Arg2, Event>` for the `EventFactory`?

Comment: @Michael, it's always Arg1 and Arg2

Answer (score 0):

Let me point out first that your choice in class names is not as good as it could be given that you are coding in Java. I would avoid the use of `Thread` that is the name of a basic class in Java and imported by default from `java.lang.*`.

There is already a `Consumer<T>` class in the last versions (1.7+ or 1.8+ not sure), and so I would also avoid using that name although is not amongst the default imports it would be still confusing to many still confusing to many. Also it seems to me that rather than Consume events it supplies event so perhaps you should consider to change towards that too.

I would suggest that you use `EventThread` or `EventProcessor` or something of the sort for the former and `EventSupplier` or `EventFactory` or similar for the latter.

About the actual design... I would say that your `Consumer` is itself a factory (thus my suggestion to call it like that) so why would you need to have yet another type for factory on top of that?

```
class Event {}
class EventSupplier<E extends Event> {
     public E get(Arg1 arg, Arg2 arg2);
}
class EventThread<E extends Event> {
     EventSupplier<E extends Event> supplier;

     public EventThread(EventSupplier<E> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
     }

     public process(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2) {
           E event = supplier.get(arg1, arg2);
     }
}
```

Now perhaps the devil is in the details that you have not disclosed, for example the main code for the thread class (e.g. where the arg1, arg2 come from?, how events are processed one after the other?) and for the Supplier or Consumer (so it actually consume the events and not just create them?)

Perhaps you want to add a real `EventConsumer` to which the thread would feed the event created by the supplier:

```
class EventConsumer<E extend Event> {
     void receive(E event) {...}
} 

class EventThread<E extends Event> {
     EventSupplier<E> supplier;
     EventConsumer<E> consumer;

     public EventThread(EventSupplier<E> supplier, EventConsumer<E> consumer) { 
     this.supplier = supplier; 
     this.consumer = consumer 
   }

   void process(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2) {
      E event = supplier.get(arg1, arg2);
      consumer.receive(event);
   }
}
```

Comment: Using a Supplier is a good idea, but how would you implement one that takes arguments? Let's say my eventFactory is actually an eventSupplier. Would you implement it differently?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what problem are you facing.... Perhaps you should write in your question what your ideal code would look like if you were able to modify Java to fit your needs and the we can answer back with the best or best correct Java idioms that would address it.

Comment: I think I was very specific, and the use of Supplier (given in the previous post) is exactly what I needed. But Supplier does not support arguments, and implementing my own is actually the same as the factory example I used (just call it supplier instead). So your answer is good but I finds it similar to my factory code

Comment: Functional interfaces a very cheap and you can create as many as you want with different parameters as you normally use lambdas to give them a body. The problem comes when the argument number and types (more the former than the latter) are not known at compilation time. If Arg1 and Arg2 are well defined. You don't need to use java.util.function.Supplier, but you need to be more careful with the way you name your classes, Supplier and Factory are good for an object creator. Thread is a no-no and your Consumer by its code looks more like a Supplier or Factory IMO.